# C++ population of unordered map using multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, hashtable, unordered

I was wondering if there was a way to speed up the population of an unordered map called (path_from_startend). The unordered map always has a unique key.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i=start_index;i<end_index;++i){    
        for (int j=start_index;j<end_index;++j){
            string key= to_string(unique_locations[i])+to_string(unique_locations[j]); 
            //dont compute path to itself
            if (i==j){
            }
            else {              
                    vector <unsigned>  path = pathbot.FindPath(unique_locations[i],unique_locations[j],turn_penalty);
                    path_from_startend.insert(make_pair(key,path));

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Since `path_from_startend` is shared between threads, the insertion operation has to go in a critical section.  Then the question is, does `pathbot.FindPath` take a long time?  Otherwise it is pointless, because you are effectively populating the map sequentially (due to the critical section).

Comment: The FindPath is a A* algorithm that does take a little bit of time (milliseconds).

Comment: Then my answer should help you.  I updated it, to match your code.

Comment: unordered_map can't be safely modified by multiple threads at once without synchronization; however it's unlikely that the insertions into the unordered_map object are your bottleneck anyway.  First thing to do is profile your process and see where the CPU is spending the majority of its time; for example you might find out that most of the time is spend creating the strings in the to_string() calls, in which case you might consider storing the data in some other (more efficient) format than text strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try whether the following pattern gains you some speed.  You are basically populating partial maps which you then merge into the whole map.  The speedup depends very much on how long the construction and insertion of the elements take.  If your elements are cheap to construct and insert, then your speedup might even be negative, because for each partial map it has to go through the whole map searching for duplicates.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
  std::unordered_map < std::string, std::vector < unsigned > > partial;

  #pragma omp for
  for (int i = start_index; i < end_index; ++i)
  {    
    for (int j = start_index; j < end_index; ++j)
    {
      std::string key = std::to_string(unique_locations[i])
                      + std::to_string(unique_locations[j]); 

      //dont compute path to itself
      if (i != j)
      {              
        std::vector<unsigned> path = pathbot.FindPath(unique_locations[i],
                                                      unique_locations[j],
                                                      turn_penalty);
        partial.insert(std::make_pair(key,path));
      }
    }
  }

  #pragma omp critical
  path_from_startend.insert(partial.begin(),partial.end());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, it really did reduce my times by quite a bit.

However, as @Jeremy mentioned, I found that :
1) Using a string as a key was quite expensive
2) I could change the algorithm up a bit to make this an O(n) operation instead of O(n^2)